# Property of modulus of a number raised to the power of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I had been trying to find the relationship between $|x^s|$ and $x^p$, where $s$ is a complex number expressed as $s=p+iq$ and $p>0$. We know that in general, $|x^s|\leq x^{|s|}$. Can I say that since $p\leq |s|$, so $x^p \leq x^{|s|}$? Please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: Your "in general" is wrong. We have $|0.5^{-1}| > 0.5^{|-1|}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x >0, s=p+iq$ with $p,q$ real then $|x^{s}|=|e^{s \ln x}|=e^{p \ln x}=x^{p}$. From this you get $|x^{s}| \leq x^{|s|}$ provided $x\geq 1$. For $0<x<1$ your inequality is false. I will let you find  counter-example with $x=\frac1 2$ and $q=0$.